# How do I make my discord.py bot recognise it's being pinged

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot via discord.py and want to create a command that shows the member's pfp. But, I want the bot to recognise when it is being pinged and it's pfp is being requested. How can I reformat this to make my bot recognise it's being refrenced or not as the member pinged (assuming the bots name and id is "Bot#1111")

Refrence command that I want the discord user to input

> ,membget @Bot#1111

```
@client.command()
async def membget(ctx, member: Member = None):
 if not member:
  member = ctx.author
 if member == "Bot#1111":
     print("1")
     await ctx.send('This is me!')
     return
 await ctx.send(member.avatar_url)
 await ctx.send('This here is a user!')
 print(member)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `if member == "Bot#1111":` you can use `if member == bot.user:`